# Snapkit constants to replace deprecated .priorityMedium() .priorityHigh() .priorityLow()?

Tags: snapkit

Does Snapkit provide constants to replace the deprecated functions .priorityMedium() .priorityHigh() and .priorityLow() ?

The suggested replacement is to use .priority(amount), but I can't find anywhere that mentions how the numbering works - is a higher number a higher priority?
ie, Can I use 0 for low, 500 for medium, and 1000 for high?

It would make sense if the deprecated methods now had constants to replace them, so I feel like I am just looking in the wrong place.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In general the higher priority the more important the constraint is so your values for low/medium/high are valid.

However after inspecting SnapKit codebase you can find this fragment with default values for required/high/medium/low.

```
public static var required: ConstraintPriority {
    return 1000.0
}

public static var high: ConstraintPriority {
    return 750.0
}

public static var medium: ConstraintPriority {
    #if os(OSX)
        return 501.0
    #else
        return 500.0
    #endif

}

public static var low: ConstraintPriority {
    return 250.0
}
```

So you can use this like `.priority(.high)` instead of `priorityHigh()`.

Comment: I've edited my answer after inspecting the SnapKit codebase